# Use of apply_filter in plugin/widget class

Tags: plugins, widgets, filters

I'm having difficulties to find out what I'm doing wrong in my use of `apply_filter()` in a widget class.

Here's some samples of my code:

```
class Byad_CountDown_Widget extends WP_Widget {
  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(
      'byadcd_widget',  // Base ID of widget
      __('BYAD Countdown Widget', 'byad-countdown'), // Widget name will appear in UI
      // Widget description & class
      array( 
        'description' => __( 'Widget for displaying a countdown (Years (opt.), Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds)', 'byad-countdown' ), 
        'classname' => 'byad-countdown',
      ) 
    );

  }

  public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

    $title = '<span class="byad-title">' . $instance['title'] . '</span><div class="arrow-container"><div class="arrow-up gray"></div><div class="arrow-up white"></div></div>';
    $title = apply_filters( 'byad_title', $title );//Try to add the possibility of changing the widget title via add_filter()

    // before and after widget arguments are defined by themes
    echo $args['before_widget'];

    // some code to implement some vars

    if ( is_active_widget( false, false, $this->id_base, true ) ) {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'byad-countdown', plugins_url( 'js/byad-countdown.js' , __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

      $params = apply_filters('byad_jsdata', array(
        'byadClass' => 'countdown-display',
        'byadImg' => '/byad-countdown/images/skull.png',
        'byadAlt' => '.',
        'year' => __('Years', 'byad-countdown'),
        'month' => __('Months', 'byad-countdown'),
        'day' => __('Days', 'byad-countdown'),
        'hour' => __('Hours', 'byad-countdown'),
        'min' => __('Minutes', 'byad-countdown'),
        'sec' => __('Seconds', 'byad-countdown'),
      ) ); //Try to modify the array passed to the JS file

      wp_localize_script( 'byad-countdown', 'jbydCD_Data', $params );
    }

    echo '<div class="countdown-display"  data-root="' . plugins_url() . '"></div>';

    if ( ! empty( $title ) ) {
      echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
    }

    echo $args['after_widget'];
  }

  // Widget Backend 
  public function form( $instance ) {
    if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
      $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
    }
    else {
      $title = __( 'My Default title', 'byad-countdown' );
    }
    //here goes Widget admin form
  }

  // Updating widget replacing old instances with new
  public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = array();
    $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
    return $instance;
  }
} // Class Byad_Countdown_Widget ends here


// Register and load the widget
function byad_load_widget() {
    register_widget( 'Byad_Countdown_Widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'byad_load_widget' );
```

As you can see I've made twice the use of apply_filter to be able to hook into the variable passed to my widget: `byad_title` and `byad_jsdata`.

But when in my theme `function.php` file I do the following:

```
function my_title($title){
  $title = 'you know what?';
  return $title;
}
add_filter('byad_title','my_title');
```

Nothing happen, even if I change the priority of the `add_filter` function

I'm looking for any advice, because after running the net and different answers and possibilities, I haven't had any success to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are missing some code in the constructor where you write `//code here` :

```
function __construct() {
    //code here
 }
```

Try replacing it with:

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(
       'byad_countdown_widget', // Base ID
        __('Byad Countdown', 'byad_countdown'), // Name
       array( 'description' => __( 'The Byad Countdown Widget', 'byad_countdown' ), ) // Args
    );
}
```

Your updated code example gives the following output:

```
<aside id="byadcd_widget-2" class="widget byad-countdown">
    <div class="countdown-display"  data-root="http://example.com/wp-content/plugins"></div>
    <h3 class="widget-title">you know what?</h3>
</aside>
```

on my `3.8.1` install with the *TwentyTwelve* theme.

So the filter seems to be working.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I didn't put my code of the `__construct()` function just to be concise. I've edited my question so you see the code.

Comment: I checked your updated code and the filter worked, see the generated HTML above.

Comment: Thanks for your testing, I'm glad it worked. Now I have to find why it doesn't on my website :-)

Comment: Maybe you got some extra `byad_title` filter call-backs in `functions.php` from your testing ? Did you try this on the default theme?

Comment: Any debug news?

Comment: Finally with a clean install with twentyfourteen theme activated, it worked like a charm. Must be something in my custom theme then. Thanks again for your help and fall back.

Comment: ok great, happy to hear that - cheers

Comment: Thanks again and finally got it to wordpress repo: 
http://wordpress.org/plugins/before-you-are-dead-countdown
I'm happy :-) Cheers

Comment: cool, congratulations!  I'm now listening to [The Final Countdown](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9jK-NcRmVcw) on YouTube to celebrate your new plugin ;-)